# Issue in connecting to Sqlite datasource

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

Iam not able to add sqlite data source because option for doing so is not visible.
I have installed system.data.sqlite also but stil not visible.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA2W5.jpg)

Comment: Connecting to and using Sqlite is explained in the [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli) and the [SQLite EF Core Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) page. Is that what you're asking? Or how to add a new connection to Visual Studio's Server Explorer?

Comment: To add an Sqlite data source to VS Source Explorer use the [Sqlite and SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox). You should probably add the [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) extension by the same author. ErikEJ's tools have become the unofficial standard for Sqlite in .NET

Comment: Not able to add sqlite db file after creating model in model first approach. See the attached image.

Comment: That's not what you asked though. I already linked to the docs that show how to use SQLite in EF, and how to add a data source. Model first went out of fashion 10 years ago, when Code-first was introduced. The intermediate "model" was completely abandoned eventually, because it only added noise. I'm not sure the model designer is even available in VS nowadays. It may be available only as an optional component. The `System.Data.Sqlite` doesn't offer any designers. These were extracted in unsupported packages that don't target 2017 or later

Comment: The ["official" SQLite designer components](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads-unsup.wiki) only support up to Visual Studio 2015. Everyone's been using ErikEJ's tools since. The EF Core Power Tools package contains visualization and code generation extensions that replace the functionality that used to be in the model-first designers